# R webscraping from html#view

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape content from the following side
http://d-portal.org/ctrack.html#view=act&aid=NL-1-PPR-100

by using the following code

```
Page <- read_html("http://d-portal.org/ctrack.html#view=act&aid=NL-1-PPR-100")
  
country_ <- Page %>% 
  html_nodes(".sector_code_text") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  paste(., collapse = "")
```

I have used similar code to scrape content from other pages, however, I'm definitely still new to webscraping.
I was wondering if the #view in the url might be an issue requiering another approach for scraping the content.
Has anyone expirienced something similar and/or can advice me how to further proceed?

Best Jens

Comment: What information are you trying to scrape?

Comment: It's the name of a country which (surprinsingly) can be found under the node .sector_code_text. Assuming that I'm reading the html page correctly (using the web-developer tool in firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that can be considered :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate('http://d-portal.org/ctrack.html#view=act&aid=NL-1-PPR-100')
remDr$executeScript("scroll(0, 5500)")
Sys.sleep(5)
page_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

read_html(page_Content) %>% html_nodes(".sector_code_text") %>%  html_text()
```

Answer (score -1):

This page uses dynamically generated content. `read_html` only reads the source html sent by the request. It will not run the javascript. You're going to need to use either Selenium or some sort of headless browser like phantomJS. Corresponding R packages to consider would be [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RSelenium) or [webdriver](https://cran.r-project.org/package=webdriver). I would try webdriver first because the former requires a separate Selenium server to be set up and running.  Webdriver requires phantomJS, but it is much easier to install.